# Question about invertibility in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Question is this: let A and B be n*n matrices s.t. AB is invertible. Prove that A and B are invertible. Then give an example that A and B need not be invertible if AB is invertible for arbitrary matrices.

For the first part. I thought about determinant and det(AB)=det(A)*det(B). 
then AB being invertible means det(AB) isn't 0, which implies that none of det(A) or det(B) can be 0. But it is in Friedberg's book and he still didn't get to determinant yet, but I don't know how to prove otherwise. Any hints?

Also if my proof with determinant is correct, how come there still exists a counter example where A,B aren't invertible but AB is invertible?

I'm sorry if my questions sound stupid.

Comment: I would use the definition of invertible matrix A: there exists M s.t. AM = MA = I

Comment: ahh ok ill try thanks.

Comment: so it's (AB)M=A(BM)=I proving A is invertible, and that M(AB)=(MA)B=I proving B is invertible? It's a simple proof by associativity?

Comment: that would work for finite n x n matrices

Answer (score 1):

The proof will depend on what results you know already.  I will assume you have the following:

> An $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is invertible if and only if there exists an $n\times n$ matrix $X$ such that $MX=I$, where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

So, suppose that $AB$ is invertible.  Then $(AB)X=I$ for some $X$, so $A(BX)=I$, so $AY=I$ where $Y=BX$, so $A$ is invertible.

There are now at least two ways you can prove $B$ is invertible, see what you can do.

For your second question: the determinant proof does not work for non-square matrices because a non-square matrix does not have a determinant.

Comment: Ah thank you! Yea the second part was what I wanted to know. :D